# Console log saved incomplete (Flask-Python)

Tags: python, logging, flask, console

I have recently built a Flask-based web interface of a software I have re-written from MATLAB to Python.
The software uses the command: "sys.stdout = open(log_file, 'w')" to re-direct the console log to a log file each time the routine is run. In the native Python version, the log file is saved without a problem. However, when the same is run using flask in a web browser. The first time the routine is run, the log file is always incomplete. Only upon refreshing, it will completely log everything. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: That's mosr likely related to buffering. In general try to use the logging module instead if such hacks.

Comment: I see. Will try to use the logging module, and look into the buffering issue. Thank you for your response.